# Issue importing Sodium in Swift

Tags: swift, sodium

What I am trying to do is to encrypt a message in swift and then decrypt it in python. So I need a reliable, safe, cross platform encryption software.

After some searching I found `Sodium`. But I am having some trouble importing the library to swift. In the podfile I specify

```
pod 'Sodium'
```

and when I do

```
pod install
```

I see: `Installing Sodium (0.8.0)` (which is the most recent version of Sodium) in green, so I know that it is installed. At the head of my viewController I put:

```
import Sodium
```

But I get:

```
Could not build Objective-C module 'Sodium'
```

and:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'OpaquePointer' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<crypto_generichash_state>' (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<crypto_generichash_blake2b_state>')
```

What gives? Why does this not work? How can I use the `Sodium` package in swift?

Comment: This will help you. https://github.com/jedisct1/swift-sodium

Answer (score 0):

This is working

- Clean DerivedData (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData)
- Change the scheme to Sodium
- Build (⌘B)
- Change back to your scheme
- Run